# xcodebuild ignores testPlan when using test-without-building

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode14.3

Consider this sample project: https://github.com/stremsdoerfer/TestPlan. This is just a Hello World that has two test plans: `TestPlanUnit` that only runs unit tests and `TestPlanUI` that only run UI tests.

Running the command below with Xcode 14.3, I'd expect `TestPlanUI` to be run, but instead only `TestPlanUnit` is run which is the default.

```
xcodebuild -scheme TestPlan -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=<sim_id>' -testPlan TestPlanUI test-without-building
```

It works fine with Xcode 14.2.
Using `test` instead of `test-without-building` also works fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Having the same issue. Discovered that today. Wow that Apple doesn't fic this immediately. This is kind of a core cuntionality for heavy CI users. It means you cannot run different test plans anymore. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @blackjacx The only work-around I've found (aside from backing off to 14.2, which I'm seriously considering) is to create a copy of my Scheme and set the default test of that scheme.

Comment: Another approach to circumvent this problem is to switch back prior using testplans, e.g. by editing the scheme with a text editor.

Answer (score 3):

Having the same problem and reported an issue to Apple. The `testPlan` parameter seems to be ignored when `test-without-building` is passed.

Answer (score 3):

I also reported `testPlan ignored when using xcodebuild test-without-building` to Apple.
Apple responded with: `Potential fix identified - For a future OS update`.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but a potential work-around until Apple fixes it. If you make a copy of your Scheme and then set the default TestPlan for that Scheme to be the test you want to run, test-without-building will pay attention to the default test in the Scheme.

I've tested with `fastlane` and directly using `xcodebuild` and both worked this way. I don't love it, especially because my schemes are fairly complex. However, I did have success getting my tests to run.

Make sure your Run variants are all built. I ran into a problem where I'd copied my schemes a while back and one scheme diverged by the **Run** / **Diagnostics** settings for the *Runtime Sanitization* for a single TestPlan. As such, that scheme wanted a binary in the `Variant-NoSanitizers` when I ran my tests in CI with sanitization turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I got a working solution that does not require any hacks

The first invocation of `xcodebuild` will create a `xctestrun` file:

```bash
xcrun xcodebuild build-for-testing -workspace <project_root>/<project_name>.xcworkspace -scheme <scheme> -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=2253C0D7-C198-44AD-A98B-11301FD88F30'
```

This file will be located in the DerivedData folder and be named like this:

```bash
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<build_folder>/Build/Products/<scheme>_<test_plan_name>_<device_type><ios-version>-<architecture>.xctestrun
```

An example would be `MyScheme_Screenshots_iphonesimulator16.4-arm64.xctestrun`

The second invocation of `xcodebuild` then uses this file to run the tests. It is not allowed to specify any of `[-project, -scheme, -workspace]` when using `-xctestrun`:

```bash
xcrun xcodebuild test-without-building -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=2253C0D7-C198-44AD-A98B-11301FD88F30' -xctestrun ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<build_folder>/Build/Products/<scheme>_<test_plan_name>_<device_type><ios-version>-<architecture>.xctestrun
```

Hope this helps you folks

**PS:** Here you can find the [Pull Request](https://github.com/Blackjacx/Assist/pull/57) for my command line tool `Snap` that integrates this fix. Snap creates screenshots using Xcode TestPlans. Super useful for CI